# Laravel Sorted Collection Gets Undone When Passed to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I am getting a collection of products with various measurement attributes and passing them to an Ajax function, but the object Ajax is receiving is unsorted even though it is sorted in the controller.

```
    public function attributes(Request $request) {
        $diameter = $request->diameter;
        $length = $request->length;
        $rate = $request->rate;
        $type = $request->type;

        $products = Attributes::when($diameter, function($query, $diameter) {
            $query->where('diameter', $diameter);
        })->when($length, function($query, $length) {
            $query->where('length', $length);
        })->when($rate, function($query, $rate) {
            $query->where('rate', $rate);
        })->when($type, function($query, $type) {
            $query->where('type', $type);
        })->get();
        
        $diameters = $products->unique('diameter')->sortBy('diameter');
        $lengths = $products->unique('length')->sortBy('length');
        $rates = $products->unique('rate')->sortBy('rate');
        $types = $products->unique('type')->sortBy('type');

        return ['diameters' => $diameters,'lengths' => $lengths,'rates' => $rates,'types' => $types];
}
```

`dd($lenghts);` returns the collection in the sorted order for length:

```
items: array:7 [
    9 => App\Models\Attribute
        ...
        "length" => "3.00""
        ...
    0 => 
        ...
        "length" => "4.00""
    1 => 
        ...
        "length" => "5.00""
    ....
```

But the object in javascript is in the unsorted order:

```
{diameters: Array(1), lengths: {…}, rates: Array(4), types: Array(1)}
diameters
: 
[{…}]
lengths
: 
0
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '4.00"', …}
4
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '5.00"', …}
5
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '6.00"', …}
6
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '7.00"', …}
7
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '8.00"', …}
8
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '9.00"', …}
9
: 
{diameter: '2.25" I.D.', length: '3.00"', …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
rates
: 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
types
: 
[{…}]
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Comment: `->sortBy()` preserves array indices, which means these Collections are returned as Objects, since JS doesn't support arrays with non-sequential indices, like PHP does via Associative Arrays. Add `->values()` after each `->sortBy(...)` to reset the array indices, starting from `0`, and you should be fine 

Comment: Personally to preserve order, I usually convert to JSON and then PARSE on the other side .. Your order should be preserved.

Comment: @Zak That's what Laravel is doing here behind the scenes actually, but Indexed arrays (starting at 0) are converted to JSON differently than associative arrays (non-sequential indices). Practical example here: https://3v4l.org/5d4oY, one array is `["one","two"]`, the other is `{"1":"two","0":"one"}` 